# Equivalentes em português para a expressão "Bitchy resting face"

Tags: expressões, tradução, tradução-inglês, termos-em-inglês

***Bitchy resting face***. Sempre quis encontrar uma boa tradução para essa expressão, definida pelo [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bitchy%20resting%20face) como:

> A blank look that makes a woman look angry all the time, even if they
>   aren't.
>
> (...)
>
> When a woman's default, or neutral, facial expression is rather bitchy
>   and mean looking in nature. She can be happy, nice and even in a great
>   mood, but she'll still have that look. They can't help it.

Answer (score 10):

Uma alternativa em Portugal podia ser «cara de cu».
No Brazil, a expressão é «cara de bunda».

Esta expressão, à semelhança da inglesa, é calão depreciativo.

Mas tem um significado ligeiramente diferente, porque *está-se com* cara de cu (é um estado temporário), mas *tem-se* "bitchy resting face" (característica permanente).

> Eh pá, andas cá com uma **cara de cu** desde que te despediram...

Comment: Onde eu moro às vezes se usa "cara de bunda", que acredito ter o mesmo significado - mas é um tantinho mais leve rsrs (P.S. "cu" não tem acento, à semelhança de "nu" - embora quase todo mundo escreva dessa forma)

Comment: @mgibsonbr acho que é a mesma expressão, [igualmente leve](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/a-palavra-cu-%C3%A9-ofensiva-no-brasil): em Portugal usamos "cu" para bunda - o rabo todo, incluindo as nádegas; ao ânus chamamos "olho do cu".

Comment: @ANeves é tipo *estar de trombas*, mas permanente... *Trombuda(o)*?

Comment: Sim, @Joum, tipo isso!

Comment: É que cara de cu nem tem esse significado. Enfim. Trombas seria a palavra

Answer (score 2):

Eu tenho outra sugestão, se calhar mais "educada" - ou pelo menos não-*calão* - **[mal-encarada](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mal-encarado)**:

> Que tem má cara. = CARRANCUDO, SISUDO

Se o calão é útil, ou então se quer um termo mais depreciativo: **[trombudo](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/trombudo)**:

> [Informal, Figurado]  Carrancudo; amuado.