# A palavra "cu" é ofensiva, no Brasil?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, uso-de-palavras

Em Portugal, a palavra *cu* é informal, mas não necessariamente ofensiva.

> - Tens as calças sujas no *cu*.
> - O miúdo caiu de *cu*.

No Brasil, ela é necessariamente ofensiva?

Que conotações ou significados diferentes tem? Só sexuais, ou outros?

Comment: "Levanta o cu e vamos embora"

Comment: Aqui no Brasil falamos "Levanta a bunda e vamos embora"

Comment: @EduMendonça   Embora não seja uma forma educada de se falar com alguém com quem tenhamos pouca intimidade, ou em um ambiente dito "fino" e "formal".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Sim, no Brasil a palavra "cu" **é um termo chulo e ofensivo**, mesmo quando dita sem a intenção de ofender.  Há uma diferença semântica entre pt-PT e pt-BR nesse sentido.  Aquilo que em Portugal chama-se "cu", no Brasil tem a denominação de "bunda".  O que nós, brasileiros, chamamos de "cu", os Portugueses chamam de "olho do cu". E o "cu", ou "olho do cu" como dizem os lusitanos, é tema de xingamentos extremamente vulgares: "vá tomar no **, seu imbecil!", "enfia no **, sua vadia!", etc.

Mesmo isoladamente, não faz sentido o uso da palavra quando podemos usar "ânus".  E se tu disseres, em um ambiente pouco informal, "estou com um problema no cu", tu serás considerado um indivíduo sem educação, ignorante e grosseiro.

Como em todas as sociedades, existem aqueles que usam palavras ditas "de baixo calão" diariamente, em qualquer local ou situação, até mesmo na frente de crianças e idosos. Esses naturalmente nem perceberão que tu estás a usar uma palavra de baixo calão. De qualquer forma, não recomendo a um visitante que deseja usar a palavra "cu", que o faça sem antes ter certeza de que está no meio desse pequeno grupo.

O fato de a palavra ser ofensiva tem mais a ver com um hábito cultural do que com a localização anatômica.  Usamos "ânus" (substantivo) e "anal" (adjetivo) sem ofender ninguém, até mesmo nos círculos "mais finos", desde que no contexto apropriado.

Comment: Tem um aforismo brasileiro antigo (e chulo) que diz: "não confunda cu com bunda".

Comment: E crianças falariam bumbum.

Comment: A palavra `cu` significa *nádega(s)* em pt-PT, mas significa *anus* em pt-BR. Por sua vez, a palavra `pica` significa *injeção* em pt-PT, mas significa *pênis* em pt-BR. Além disso, a palavra `puto` significa *menino* em pt-PT, mas significa *prostituto* em pt-BR. Assim, a frase `o puto levou pica no cu` pode soar completamente inocente em Portugal e extremamente ofensiva no Brasil.

Comment: Também usamos no Brasil "olho do cu", com o mesmo significado que no português Europeu. Porem no Brasil como ambas são palavrões, quando se diz algo como "vai tomar no olho do seu c*", há uma ligeira intensidade na ofensa, ao menos eu a interpreto assim.

Comment: @Luciano   Discordo.  Acho que incluir "o olho" pode dar mais satisfação a quem xinga, porque é menos comum e a frase mais longa.  Mas em termos de ofensa, se eu disser para uma senhora de "educação fina" a referida frase, com "olho" ou "sem olho", acho que a ofensa e a reação serão as mesmas.  É minha opinião.

Comment: Em discussões informais e descontraídas sobre sexo, é normal falar `cu` ou outros apelidos quaisquer para orgãos geniais, etc.

Comment: @Filburt   Depende de quem está presente.  Uma psicóloga da USP fez uma palestra descontraída sobre sexo em uma livraria, com muitos jovens universitários presentes, e eu só ouvi "ânus", "coito anal", "penetração" e palavras desse tipo.

Comment: @Centaurus Apesar de poder-se descontrair com brincadeiras e piadas, não acho que uma palestra numa livraria seja lugar para todo tipo de informalidade. Não é como um show de stand-up comedy, por exemplo.

Answer (score 13):

Sim, é ofensivo. No Brasil "cu" é equivalente a "olho do cu" em Portugal.

Existem dois jeitos que não são ofensivos para designar essa parte do corpo humano (o traseiro) no português brasileiro: bunda e bumbum.

Eu traduziria os exemplos que você citou assim:

- Tens as calças sujas no cu. = Você está com as calças sujas na bunda
  (ou "no bumbum", para soar mais educado)
- O miúdo caiu de cu. = O menino caiu de bunda.

Comment: "cu" é sem acento.

Comment: @JorgeB. Ele já é o próprio assento.

Comment: Só para clarificar aqui tanto usamos "cu" para bunda como para "olho do cu". Embora a última expressão seja mais rude que a primeira.

Comment: Vou ser ordinário mas é para perceberem a ideia "vai levar no ** que tens um ** que é uma categoria.". Talvez no Brasil fosse "vai tomar no ** que você tem uma bunda gostosa."

Comment: Não diga bumbum se você for um adulto. Se quiser ser "educado", diga apenas "Sua calça está suja atrás"; e se quiser falar de bundas pode usar a palavra nádegas, desde que num contexto anatômico.

Comment: "Bunda" pode ser ofensivo, pelo menos de onde eu vim e onde eu estou. O termo neutro é "traseiro": *Suas calças estão sujas no traseiro*. *Nádegas* também serve, porém só se refere ao corpo propriamente dito; as calças não tem nádegas. *Nalga* também não é ofensivo, mas é castelhanismo, e só usado, creio, no Rio Grande do Sul rural. *Bunda* não pode ser usado em nenhum contexto formal, embora eu imagine que muitos a usem num contexto familiar. *Bumbum* é infantil, e não é usado entre adultos a não ser que sejam íntimos ou que a intenção seja jocosa.

Comment: (@LuísHenrique embora não seja a mais usada, a palavra "nalga" é comum em Portugal.)

Answer (score 4):

Gostaria de incluir o fato de que na linguagem informal entre **amigos íntimos**, você encontrará usos não ofensivos e expressões do tipo:

> **Amigo do Fulano**
>
> Fedeu?
>
> **Fulano**
>
> Fedeu nada... Vai lá no banheiro e cheira.
>
> **Amigo do Fulano**
>
> Teu cu.

Ou então.

> **Fulano**
>
> Égua, Jogos Vorazes é a melhor triologia de todos os tempos.
>
> **Amigo do Fulano**
>
> Teu cu.

Neste caso específico, "Teu cu" poderia ser entendido como uma versão íntima e não ofensiva de "Você não deve estar falando a verdade."

Não estou completamente seguro a respeito da generalidade desses exemplos, mas certamente não fazem parte de regionalismo ou dialetos. Talvez micro-culturas espalhadas por periferias e, por que não, escolas da classe média.

Comment: Nunca ouvi essas expressões.  Se você é brasileiro certamente nós frequentamos lugares bem diferentes.  Em que estado brasileiro "teu cu" é uma gíria com o significado de "não estás falando a verdade"?

Comment: Bem vindo ao meu mundo. Não se espante, conflitos de realidade são comuns em sociedades individualizadas e propensas à segregração social. Não me sentirei ofendido com o tom do seu comentário. Ficarei grato por lhe apresentar uma nova forma, uma expressão.

Comment: cpicanco, desculpe-me, não houve a intenção de ofender ninguém. Minha intenção foi dizer que sendo o Brasil um país tão grande, provavelmente tu vives em um local por onde nunca passei.  Pode até ser que seja um socialeto ou idioleto, e que seja falado na periferia da minha cidade, mas imaginei que fosse um regionalismo.

Comment: Mais um exemplo. Não vá dizer isso a qualquer um! Você precisa de ter alguma intimidade. :)

Comment: Qual o amigo que se sentiria ofendido com um "foda-se" (não ofensivo)?

Comment: Eu já ouvi isso, inclusive excluí uma resposta do [pt.so] por causa da expressão (e o restante da resposta era vago). Claramente é inadequada lá (mas não aqui na sua resposta).

Comment: A minha avó dizia, em Portugal, *nariz no cu* com o significado de *não me chateies, isso não me interessa.* Talvez uma contração de *vai meter o nariz no cu* de sabe-se lá quem.

Comment: @cpicanco - "Foda-se" não é ofensivo entre amigos, mas "vá se foder" com certeza é. Então não tenho muita certeza de que se possa dizer "teu cu", mesmo entre amigos, da forma como você sugere, sem provocar uma reação igualmente grosseira. (Ouço com frequência, nessa acepção, "meu cu": ***Meu cu** que o Flamengo é melhor do que o Cruzeiro.*) E, a propósito, "égua!", como interjeição, creio que é regionalismo paraense.

Comment: @LuísHenrique  Pois eu não ouço nem "teu cu" e nem "meu cu".  Eu ouço "**No cu** que o Flamengo é melhor que o Fluminense".

Answer (score 0):

Sim, porque nossa sociedade mais antiga considerava nojento e vergonhoso falar de coisas naturais que produzem desconforto ou falar de orifícios que liberam dejetos do corpo humano; dejetos estes que sejam desagradáveis e que tenham mau cheiro, tipo: escarro vômitos e fezes. Todavia com o avanço da medicina e outras ciências, as pessoas foram se tornando menos ignorantes e vaidosas, aceitando a vida com naturalidade. Outro viés, é que a palavra cu aqui no Brasil também é usada para ofender e praguejar outras pessoas, uma forma agressiva de desabafo ou liberar estresse. 
Mais sobre este termo
Significado de Cu. substantivo masculino [Pejorativo] Abertura corporal por onde são expelidos os excrementos, as fezes, situada na extremidade do intestino grosso; ânus. P. analogia. A parte que se refere ao fundo da agulha; numa agulha, a extremidade oposta a ponta.
[image]
[enter link description here](https://www.dicio.com.br/cu/)